# single-{post_type}.php is not loaded despite flushing rules

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have the following code to define my `producto` custom type post:

```
add_action('init', 'custom_post_producto');
function custom_post_producto() {
  $args = array(
    "label"               => 'Productos',
    "labels"              => $labels,
    "description"         => "Artículos a la venta dentro del sitio web.",
    "public"              => true,
    "publicly_queryable"  => false,
    "show_ui"             => true,
    "show_in_rest"        => false,
    "has_archive"         => false,
    "show_in_menu"        => true,
    "exclude_from_search" => true,
    "capability_type"     => "page",
    "map_meta_cap"        => true,
    "hierarchical"        => false,
    // "rewrite"          => array( "slug" => "producto", "with_front" => true ),
    "rewrite"             => true,
    "query_var"           => true,
    "menu_icon"           => "dashicons-products",        
    "supports"            => array( "title", "thumbnail" )
  );

  register_post_type("producto", $args);
  // flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

And, as the question title poses, `single-{post_type}.php` is not being loaded and redirects to the site index.

Now, I've been for hours trying to track down this problem. I've tried flushing rewrite rules with `flush_rewrite_rules()` right after `register_post_type()`, changing (and even deleting) the `rewrite` attribute in the `$args` array, resaving the Permalink Settings, and even installing the [Rewrite Rules Inspector plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/) to check if everything is right and flushing the rewrite rules again and again, to no avail. I even reinstalled the whole site and entered new info, but the problem persists.

For the record, I'm working on `localhost` using XAMPP 5.6.19 on Windows 10, and working with Wordpress 4.5.2.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `publicly_queryable` has to be true for single posts to display on the front end. or you can just delete that line and it will default to the value of `public`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe it was that attribute all this time! Does `public` affect if the template is shown? And `has_archive` or `rewrite`?

Comment: I've added an answer which answers this for you, and links to the docs which explain much more. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flushing the rewrite rules - which you can do just by visiting the Settings -> Permalinks page - was a good step to take, because it's usually the overlooked cause of these sorts of issues.

However as Milo said in the comments, in this case, it's just that the `publicly_queryable` argument needs to be true if you want these posts to display on the frontend.

From the [docs for register_post_type()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments):

> **public**
>   (boolean) (optional) Controls how the type is visible to authors (`show_in_nav_menus`, `show_ui`) and readers (`exclude_from_search`, `publicly_queryable`).
>   *Default: false*
>
> **publicly_queryable**
>   (boolean) (optional) Whether queries can be performed on the front end as part of parse_request().
>   *Default: value of public argument*

As you can see - and again as Milo said - just avoiding setting `publicly_queryable` will make things a bit simpler for you in this case.

I would definitely recommend reading up on those docs to understand what each of the attributes do, but I realise it can be difficult to get your head around at first!

As for your second question in the comments:

> Does `public` affect if the template is shown? And `has_archive` or `rewrite`?

- **`public`** is a quick override to generally control all of the backend and frontend visibility of your post type in one go: unless you override it with any of the four more explicit options as seen above. For the frontend, these are `publicly_queryable`, as we have already addressed, and `exclude_from_search`. You've already set `exclude_from_search` to true, so no matter what you set for `public`, this post type won't be found in searches (OR taxonomy term lists).
- **`has_archive`** won't affect whether your single post types can be viewed, but it will turn on and off the option to view the archive 'loop' of all of your posts - at http://example.com/your_rewrite_slug
- **`rewrite`** doesn't affect public visibility of your posts; just what the URL will be. The URL has to be something though, so if you don't set the rewrite value, it'll just default to your post_type name - in this case 'producto'

Each of these are also covered in the docs, so I'll mention again - definitely read up on it. The investment will be worth it! :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough answer, I've checked the documentation and, alongside your answer, now I understand much better how do these attributes work, and I've toyed around with these options to actually see its effects. Your help is way appreciated. :)

Comment: @noquierouser Fantastic! Always glad to hear that an answer has helped someone learn how something really works, rather than just providing a piece of code to drop in somewhere :) Now you can probably teach others this!